# Opendds-3.13 Release build failure

Tags: qt, opendds

I'm making release build of my Application in QT + opendds-3.13 i m getting this error.

> ..\OpenDDS-3.13\ACE_wrappers\ace/OS_NS_netdb.inl(794): error C2440:
>   'return': cannot convert from 'WCHAR *' to 'const ACE_TCHAR *'

although i can successfully build the debug version only facing this problem in release build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely you have incorrect compiler settings, check especially the unicode settings of your project.

Comment: but the debug version build is working fine, its successfully build and run although when I build the release version its throw that error. I am using QT Framework.

Comment: it could be that there are differences between the debug and release settings, just compare them